# How to set data into Generic classes?

Tags: java, database, generics, reflection

I want to read data from my database and set them into my classes which are different, such as `student.class`, `staff.class` and so on. After set the data, they will be put into an `ArrayList`. Each class has their own get and set methods for each field. I want to use reflection as a solution, but I　don't know how to type the code. Can anyone give my some advice?

Here is my code:

```
public ArrayList<E> selectFromDatabase(String tableName, HashMap<String, String> condition) {

    ArrayList<E> list = new ArrayList<>();
    ResultSet rs = null;
    String sql = getSql(SELECT, tableName, null, condition);

    try {
        rs = executeSql(sql);
        while (rs.next()) {
            E e = new E();
            Class<?> aClass = e.getClass();
            Method[] methods = aClass.getMethods();
            for (Method m:methods) {
                //How to set data to into the generics class？
            }
            list.add(e);
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }

    return list;
}
```

Comment: This isn't the way to go here.  Typically, each table in your database schema will have a known and fixed type, and you would load each record into one instance of that class.

Comment: Have a look at Hibernate, which is one way to handle your problem: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/

Comment: [MyBatis](http://www.mybatis.org/mybatis-3/) could be also good option

Comment: Depend of you querry you can get the data of whay you want. The result will give you an object with the results you want.

Comment: You would be wise to learn [JPA](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/partpersist.htm).